# Building a custom view for Android Lollipop that's backward compatible (with little code duplication)

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I want to build a custom view for Android-L with support for the four-arguments constructor:

```
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

which ideally would call the super constructor and then do some inititalization work:

```
MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

  // initialize lots of static members here
}
```

and have the other constructors implemented by delegating to this one:

e.g.

```
 MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
   this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
 }
```

The problem with this is that this will fail on non-L devices because the super constructor with four arguments doesn't exist.

So, my current workaround is to implement the three and the four-argument constructors (which are mostly copy and paste) and live with it.

Does anyone see a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: have a method with all the initialization code, and call it from the four constructor. This way the only repeated line of code is the methods' call

Answer (score 1):

Create a method like this:

```
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    // ...
}
```

Then have each constructor call the `init()` method with the desired arguments.